# Invoke a Macro Using A Macro Variable Name

Tags: callback, sas, metaprogramming, pass-by-reference, sas-macro

Is it possible in SAS to invoke a call to a macro using a macro variable whose value is the macro's name? Something like the following:

```
%MACRO TEST (macroName, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);

    %put LOG: %&macroName(&var1);

%MEND;
%TEST(testName,testVar1);
```

---

In response to Richard's answer. I tried following your solution, but am still getting an "apparent invocation of macro YearMonthString not resolved" using the following code:

```
%MACRO YearMonthString(nYear,nMonth);
/* Builds a string in the format YYYYMM using passed nYear and nMonth */

    %local returnVal;

    /*Build the string */
    %let returnVal = &nYear.%AddLeadingZerosToMakeNumXLength(2,&nMonth);

    /*Write to LOG */
    %put MACRO LOG: YearMonthString(nYear= &nYear, nMonth= &nMonth) will return &returnVal;

    /* return returnVal */
    &returnVal

%MEND;
%MACRO TEST (macroName, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);

    %local loopCount;   

    %let loopCount = 1;

    %do i=1 %to 13;
        %&macroName.(&var1,&loopCount);
        %let loopCount = %eval(&loopCount+1);
    %end;

%MEND;
%TEST(YearMonthString,2018,8,,,);
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a macro named YearMonthString defined? There is no `%macro` statement to define YearMonthString in your posted code.

Comment: You might want to restart your SAS session to begin fresh.  The macro emits a value via `&returnVal` and the macro invocation is followed by a semi-colon, which will also enter the SAS 'source code' flow, and thus the returnval will be 'interpreted' as a statement, of which there is none.  Are you trying to generate a macro value that contains a space separated list of items that is a 13-month list of months starting from some given month ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can!  The construct is `%` `&`*macro-symbol*.  Here is a demonstration:

```
%macro one();
  %put &SYSMACRONAME;
%mend;

%macro two();
  %put &SYSMACRONAME;
%mend;

%macro dispatch (routine);
  %&routine.()
%mend;

%dispatch (one)
%dispatch (two)

---- LOG ----
13   %dispatch (one)
ONE
14   %dispatch (two)
TWO
```

Comment: Just a style question @Richard, you like putting a space before the parentheses for a macro parameter list?  I don't think I've seen that much.  Could help readability, but I'm not sure how long it would take me to get used to the idea.  I have started putting a space before semicolons that end a statement.

Comment: It's not a 100% conscious decision -- sometimes deep in *frameworky* code I'll forgo a space.  Mostly when there is some top-level invocations going on I'll add a space to separate actor (the macro) from the actions (the parameters).  I would guess that at some point in the past some hard-learned lessons were that somehow adding the space saved my bacon more times than not having the space -- or maybe it was just 'Yay, I have escaped the ISPF editor'

Comment: Other times I'll place each parameter on a separate line, or use a macro variable and it's resolution to repeat a long list a same valued parameters that are used in many similar but slightly varied macro invocations.

Comment: Thx. I’ve definitely done the macro parameters on their own line thing. I like it, esp for 3 or more parameters. If I can reteach my fingers may try the one space for a project and see if I like the look.

Comment: I guess the best style rule is "Be consistent, unless you are lazy or don't want to" hahaha

Comment: I use space before semicolon, all macro syntax in upper case (%-statements, macro variables), regular code in lower case.

Comment: @ChrisJ do you find it difficult do that all that UPCASEing.  I would think it rather tedious.  Do you have an editor macro to help with that?

Comment: Not really, just all comes naturally now, barely impacts coding speed.