# (SAS) Passing a function as an argument to a function (or macro)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

In a modern language (e.g.python), you could do something like

```
def do_a_thing(foo,bar):
    thing = (... do a thing to foo(bar) ...)
    return thing
```

How does one do this (or something similar enough) in SAS? In my concrete application I have defined a bunch of functions, and need to do the same thing to all of them, so I thought it would be nice to have a function that takes a function as an argument and then *does the thing* to that function, and then apply it where needed. The "obvious" solution doesn't work, e.g. in a `proc fcmp` doing this:

```
function do_a_thing(foo,bar);
    thing = (... do a thing to foo(bar) ...)
return(thing);
endsub;
```

This fails because SAS doesn't know about any function called `foo`, and throws an error.

I expect the answer involves some macro trickery, but I find the macro system somewhat opaque and can't quite figure it out. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: SAS does not have user defined functions. So macros are the only way to emulate them. Sad!

Comment: Whatever it is `proc fcmp` lets you do, sure looks like user defined functions to me? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: That could be a way to pack a macro into a function, introduce it into the *normal* scope, and make it persistent. Most users don't get that deep.

Comment: How can you do something TO a function? You use a function to RETURN something based on the inputs you give it.  How you approach a particular problem in a particular language depends on how that language works. Post a particular problem you want to solve and what you attempted to do to solve it.

Comment: @Tom: That just it, I am asking how to approach this problem (doing a thing depending on a specified function, where that function can vary) in SAS. Reproducing this kind of functionality, _however it may be done_, is the particular problem I want to solve.

Comment: Still sounds like an XY problem to my. In this case problem Y is how to use lambda functions but you haven't presented any concrete X problem.

Comment: While great for programming, this kind of abstraction or templating can be a hindrance to downstream maintenance/understanding (like 5+ years).  Best case uses are when there is good design documentation.  Some applications are implementation of VERB ACTION dispatch designs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really shown an example where this might be required (or even useful).

But in general in SAS you would use code generation to implement that type of mis-direction. For example your second "function" could be a statement style macro. That is macro that only emits part of a statement to be included into the actual SAS program you want to create.

```
%macro do_a_thing(function,arglist);
  &function(&arglist)
%mend;
```

Then you might use it in a program

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  mean = %do_a_thing(mean,of _numeric_);
  std = %do_a_thing(std,of _numeric_);
run;
```

For more complex things you will have more trouble. The new-ish DOSUBL() function might help in that they can allow you to run multiple steps in a separate execution space.  But for most things the performance cost might be too high to make it worth while.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Show your code regarding *defined a bunch of functions*.

Macro, at it's core, is a text generating system with side effects.  Macro can perform dispatch like processing using indirect resolution -- see answer [Invoke a Macro Using A Macro Variable Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099077/invoke-a-macro-using-a-macro-variable-name/52099299)

If you are trying to code a general purpose function invokable from DATA Step, SQL, %SYSFUNC, or DS2 both Proc FCMP and DS2 can create user defined functions (UDF).  The method(or function)-name to invoke (or dispatch, or APPLY) would likely have to be passed as a string into said UDF.

You will also want to look into `DOSUB` and `DOSUBL`

> **Details**
>
> The DOSUBL function enables the immediate execution of SAS code after a text string is passed. Macro variables that are created or updated during the execution of the submitted code are exported back to the calling environment.
>
> DOSUBL returns a value of zero if SAS code was able to execute, and returns a nonzero value if SAS code was not able to execute.

As for modern... SAS SCL had CALL APPLY ages ago -- sadly SCL never made it to the Foundation product or escaped the confines of SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know anything about SAS, but in general you would need some way to make a difference between make a function call and passing a parameter..

A Google search for the title of this question led me here, perhaps it might help you:

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/how-to-pass-a-parameter-with-macro-variables-into-macro/td-p/330627#messageview_4